# Laptop turned off without charged

Tags: linux, laptop, power-supply, battery, power

I have a Asus N55SF laptop, and always when I unplug my device from the charger  it immediately shuts down - the battery decreases from 100% to 1% in few seconds.

Perhaps the problem is with my i7 and with the power plans for my laptop.

For example today, without a charger my laptop was working for 30 minutes, and then when I run a big calculation (neural network) the laptop turned off in 1 sec with 1% of battery.

Do anybody know what is wrong?

My logs:

```
➜ ~ acpi -ib
Battery 0: Unknown, 85%
Battery 0: design capacity 4816 mAh, last full capacity 2099 mAh = 43%
➜ ~ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTek
  model:                N55--52
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              wto, 31 mar 2015, 22:45:56 (23 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    energy:              21,351 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         24,926 Wh
    energy-full-design:  57,2 Wh
    energy-rate:         0,0472518 W
    voltage:             11,875 V
    percentage:          85%
    capacity:            43,5769%
    technology:          lithium-ion

➜ ~
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the ACPI data your battery is already fairly worn - ~43.5% rated life left.

It seems like although there is still >40% of rated life remaining the battery is unable to supply enough current to power your laptop at full load. Therefore I would suggest these possible solutions:

1. Contact your vendor, see if this is normal and if not check if the battery is still covered under warranty.
2. Throttle your CPU so that it does not draw too much power - this will slow down your laptop during heavy calculation though. (You probably want to throttle only while on Battery power too...)
3. Replace your battery.

Comment: thanks for answer, I have that problem for long time, from the times when my batter is 84% rated life ;) It's quite crazy. I will try to throttle my cpu.